# Convert map to list of values of the same map

Tags: mule, dataweave

i have got a Map where key is String and value is List of String and i have to convert into List with dataweave. How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it:
%function listToMap(list) {
codRamo: (list map $.codRamo) joinBy "','",
codRisc: (list map $.codRisch) joinBy "','",
codOgge: (list map $.codOgge) joinBy "','" } 
as :object{class: "java.util.HashMap"}